# Magento Custom Collection

Tags: database, magento, orm, entity-attribute-value

all over?

I have the following business rule: in my list of products, need to bring some data that go beyond standard data, the data would be the categories that he shall belong,
but ordered by the categories that have higher level, I will explain:

My tree categories: (*) product belongs to category

```
-- Root

---- Furniture *
------ Living Room
------ Bedroom

---- Electronics
------ Cameras
-------- Accessories *
-------- Digital Cameras *
------ Cell Phones
-------- Smartphone

---- Computers 
------ Build Your Own *
------ Laptops
-------- Nice
---------- Power *
-------- Master *
------ Hard Drives

---- Apparel 
------ Shirts 
------ Shoes 
------ Mens *
------ Womens 
------ Hoodies
```

Return ordered by level:

```
level-4 - Power

level-3 - Digital Cameras
level-3 - Accessories
level-3 - Master

level-2 - Build Your Own
level-2 - Mens

level-1 - Furniture
```

Sure, it could be done quickly, so they had access to the id of the product I would do another search on the bench taking in all the categories and then make it.
Do not like this way, it would cost me twice as much processing and query the database, as I said is a solution, but wish that the collection itself he can also join with the table of categories.

Thank you, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this page out: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/24947/

There is some decent code on there about building a tree.  From this example, you should be able to utilize `level` and order it the way you need to.